# How can we use H2 to test SQL Server code that involves date to string conversions?

Tags: date, sql-server-2012, string-formatting, h2

We use the [H2 database engine](http://www.h2database.com/) as part of our test tooling for a product that uses SQL Server 2012 in production. Some of the existing SQL views use [the three-argument CONVERT function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms187928.aspx) on dates to format them as "ODBC Canonical" date:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR, some_date, 120)
```

Normally when we encounter a situation like this we do one of the following two things:

1. we replace the SQL with something portable that works in MS SQL and H2
2. we implement a JAVA function to match MS SQL's behaviour and [map it as UDF into H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#user_defined_functions)

At the moment both seem to fail us since MS SQL doesn't seem to offer an alternative way of formatting dates and `CONVERT` is already a function in H2, just not in the three argument form.

We seem to be left with two options that we don't really like:

3. add a layer of in-direction on both sides, by defining a UDF in MS SQL that runs the convert, with a corresponding one in H2,
4. patch H2

The issue with the former is that it will introduce something into production that is solely for testing. That is true to some extent for migrating to more portable SQL as well, but adding the UDF is going a step further.

Patching H2 could be an option, but it is hard to tell how much effort that would be, in particular considering the existing `CONVERT` function. If suitable for a wider audience we would have to also cover MS SQL's weird world of styles across the types in a reasonable fashion, whereas we are only after one style for dates.

Is there another way? Has anyone experience with solving this problem?

Comment: What version of SQL Server? SQL 2012 has the FORMAT function. I don't quite understand what you're doing though. Are you converting a SQL Server database to H2 to test it in H2? There are other ways to format dates without using the CONVERT function, i.e. use `DATEPART` and `CAST`

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid it's 2012 - I edited the question to reflect that. What we do is to test a full web stack on top of H2 instead of SQL Server to speed up getting into known state. We add the schema via Liquibase, maybe load some data via SQL, then spin up the application and run Selenium tests against it.

Comment: If you're building a system in SQL but then testing it in H2 then it seems you're not testing the system? I'm missing something here.PS I altered tags to say SQL 2012. Will using functions other than CONVERT (FORMAT and/or CAST) solve your problem? Surely there is more than one function mismatch between SQL Server and H2?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid the SQL is a very small part of the overall system, and H2 does a reasonable job simulating SQL Server. It's nowhere near perfect, but the gaps are understood. It's a tradeoff vs. the cost of getting known state into a SQL Server database. What we normally do with missing functions is to implement a UDF, this is the first one that clashes with an existing function. Your proposed `FORMAT` function might do the trick for that, H2 doesn't have a function of that name.

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent result using the FORMAT function is:

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
```

It seems that using the FORMAT function instead of CONVERT may resolve your issue.

Another way without using CONVERT is this:

```
SELECT 
CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-' + 
CAST(MONTH(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-' + 
CAST(DAY(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(2))
```

(this is just an example and does not contain time components)